# SQL copy data from a column to another column from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `DEP` and `DEPARTMENTS`.

I want to copy the data from `DEPARTMENT`'s column called `ID_DEPARTMENT` to `DEP`'s column called `ID`, but I keep getting either errors or says that nothing was updated.

Comment: please share error you have got and query you have used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is just that column then you can copy the data and insert it into new rows using:

```sql
INSERT INTO dep (id )
SELECT id_department FROM DEPARTMENTS;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE departments (id_department, col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'a'||LEVEL, 'b'||LEVEL, 'c'||LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE dep(id INT);
```

Then, after the `INSERT`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dep;
```

Outputs:

> | ID |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |
> | 4 |
> | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55d64522c3ff2fc9ac024bb7af33d7a0)*